# mysql inverse text search from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables.

First contain list of used  words, second keep black list of words which can't be shown ever.

First table (A) example

```
+---------------+
| keyword       |
+---------------+
| php           |
| php developer |
| developer     |
| c#            |
+---------------+
```

Second table (B) example:

```
+-----------+
| word      |
+-----------+
| developer |
| foo       |
| music     |
+-----------+
```

I have to show everything from 1st table except rows which fully or partially contain words  from second table.
Based on content above, for instance, i should show only two rows
php and c#.

How i can reach the same result with help SQL (very good if it will be one)

I can make only this

```
select * from A where keyword not in(select word from B);
```

but it's strict comparision. it's not enough to me.

Any advice are welcome.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be something like this:

```
select keyword from A where keyword not in
   (select A.keyword from A
    inner join B on A.keyword like '%' + B.keyword + '%')
```

You select all the words from A that contain words of B and afterwords you select the other words.

Comment: for mysql seems instead % + keyword + % might be used concat() function
and yes thank you for comment they are working well

Comment: Note this solution is not optimal and will slow down on large sets of data (more than it should). As it will query table `A` twice rather than just restricting table A to those which don't match. See my answer for a solution that doesn't query table `A` twice.

Answer (score 4):

You want:

```
SELECT keyword FROM A 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM B 
    WHERE A.keyword LIKE '%' + B.word + '%' )
```

Note that doing this kind of like query with a `%` at the start of the term causes indexes on `B.word` to not be used.

My test code (using SQL Server so the table declares for testing are TSQL but still relevant):

```
DECLARE @A TABLE
(
keyword varchar(50)
)

DECLARE @B TABLE
(
word varchar(50)
)

INSERT INTO @A VALUES ('php'), ('php developer'), ('Developer'), ('C#')
INSERT INTO @B VALUES ('developer'), ('fcuk'), ('music')

SELECT keyword  FROM @A A WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM @B B WHERE a.keyword LIKE '%' + B.word + '%')
```

Results:

```
keyword
php
C#
```

Edit: A little more explanation:

This query is the logical extension of your query:

```
select * from A
where keyword not in(
    select word from B);
```

Which can be written as the following (which is logically the exact same):

```
SELECT * FROM A 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM B 
    WHERE A.keyword = B.word)
```

What we want is to do is exclude records where the A.keyword `contains` the `B.Word` value. This is done by pre-pending and appending a `'%'` character and performing a `LIKE` rather than `=`

thus the query becomes:

```
SELECT * FROM A 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM B 
    WHERE A.keyword LIKE = '%' + B.word + '%')
```

The `SELECT 1 1` is just pointless and can equally be `SELECT *` if you rather, they both to the same thing inside an `EXISTS` statement and there's many answers here on StackOverflow dedicated to explaining why they're the same.

Comment: +1 Depending on whether keywords can be entered as upper/lower case and whether case sensitivity is enabled in the OP's database, it may be useful to explicitly convert both a.keyword and B.word to lower case when joining on them.

Comment: yes you are right about quantity of queries to one table, like above suggested, but could you more explain your query ?